# Delete worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run code that deletes all worksheets bar three.

The code below results in a syntax error:

```
Sub Delete_Sheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1", "LBO", "Factset codes" Then ws.Delete
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You had a surplus `End If` which I have removed.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put all "Names to check" in one line like that. Try this (replace the If block of yours):

```
Select Case ws.Name 
    Case "Sheet1", "LBO", "Factset codes"' Do Nothing here
    Case Else: ws.Delete
End Select
```

**EDIT** (Add code to make it silent delete):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Sheet1", "LBO", "Factset codes" ' Do Nothing here
    Case Else
        If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then ws.Delete
End Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than loop through all sheets and test for three names, you could more simply move the three sheets you want to a new book:

This can be done in a single line, you could add further code to close the original workbook, error handling to check all these sheets exist etc.

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Factset code", "LBO")).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

While @PatricK's answer is the most elegant, the problem with your code is the if statement, if you have multiple criteria, you have to write something along the lines of:

```
If Not ws.Name = "Sheet1" And Not ws.Name = "LBO" And Not ws.Name = "Factset codes" Then
    ws.Delete
End If
```

On a side note if you write the code to execute if logic test is true on the same line as the logic test like so:

```
If Not ws.Name = "Sheet1" And Not ws.Name = "LBO" And Not ws.Name = "Factset codes" Then ws.Delete
```

you don't need the `End If` statement.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm receiving a "Run-time error '1004'" Method 'Delete of object'_Worksheet' failed, on the "ws.Delete" component of the code, is i tpossible to avoid this?

Comment: Check your workbook, it might be that none of your sheets are matching the criteria thus the macro tries to delete all sheets but a workbook cannot have 0 sheets. You could add `And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count > 1` to the `If` statement. This way if there is only one sheet, it is kept regardless of the name.